# DocuSign error: Open the following URL in your browser to grant consent to the application

Tags: docusignapi

When I try ti authenticate through docusign api client:

```
dsApi = new docusign.ApiClient();
dsApi.setOAuthBasePath(process.env.dsOauthServer.replace('https://', '')); // it should be domain only.
let rsaKey = fs.readFileSync(process.env.privateKeyLocation);
const results = await dsApi.requestJWTUserToken(
        process.env.dsJWTClientId,
        process.env.impersonatedUserGuid,
        SCOPES,
        rsaKey,
        jwtLifeSec
      );
```

I get an error: *"Error: Open the following URL in your browser to grant consent to the application: [https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature+impersonation&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent"](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature+impersonation&client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent%22)*

If I open the url, I see this:

[image]

edit: this is what I do step by step:

1. Navigate to **Apps and Keys** and click on **Quickstart** to generate a sample project.
2. Rename the project name to `Quickstart App-3`
3. Pick Node.js project
4. Select project type -> **Multiple code examples**
5. Download the project

If I open my quickstart's app details, these are the redirects urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/authorization-code/callback | http://localhost:8080/ds/callback | https://localhost:9090/ds/callback | https://localhost:8000/ds/callback | https://localhost:44333/ds/callback | https://localhost:44333/ds/login?authType=JWT | https://localhost:44333/ds/login?authType | https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent | http://localhost:8080/login&type=acg | http://localhost:8080/login&type=jwt | http://localhost:3000/ds/callback | https://localhost:3000/ds/callback | http://localhost:8080/public/index.php?page=ds_callback | http://127.0.0.1:3000/ds/callback | http://localhost:3000/auth/docusign/callback | https://localhost:3000/auth/docusign/callback
```

6. Unzip the project archive and open it in VS Code. Navigate with terminal to `jwt_console_project` folder and install npm packages by `npm install`.
7. Copy **private.key** file from config folder to **jwt_console_project** folder
8. Rename **jwtConfig.example.json** file to **jwtConfig.json**
9. Edit **jwtConfig.json** file and set `dsJWTClientId` and `impersonatedUserGuid` variables. Environment variables look like this:

[image]

10. Run project by `npm run start` and I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the [Apps and Keys page](https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=appsAndKeys), find your IK (client ID or Integration Key) and add the URL "https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent" to the list of authorized URIs.

If this IK was automatically created with quickstart and you followed the quickstart code, then this may be something we need to fix on our end.

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks. I created a docusign app through quickstart and there should be all required urls. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. I provided more details in my original question.

Comment: Matt, what lang did you select for quickstart? and what package option? (the last question has 3 choices)

Comment: node.js and third option (Multiple code examples)

Comment: I just tried this myself and did not have this issue. Can you please try again from the beginning and confirm? Maybe record a video showing what you're doing or take notes?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, now if I open the url  https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature+impersonation&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent" it works

Answer (score 1):

That error message is **not** from the SDK. It is from an example that uses the SDK. Here's the [source line](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/jwt_console_project/jwtConsole.js#L27) for the Node.js example.

Anyhoo, as Inbar says, the problem is that the redirect URL needs to be set in the for the Client ID (integration key).

See my [blog post on consent](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent) for background and details.

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for checking my question. I created a docusign app through quickstart and there should be all required urls. I am still getting the same error. I provided more details in my original question.